# Center buttons in a view horizontally

Tags: titanium

I have buttons I want to center horizontally in a view. There are three, and all I can seem to get is:

```
[button1-button2-button3------------------------------]
```

What I really want is

```
[--------button1--------button2--------button3--------]
```

These buttons are dynamic widths too. The amount of buttons will change, some views have 1, others have 2 or 3. Depending on an action, the number of buttons can change. I need this support both iOS and android.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting the screen into `n` different columns using percentage layout. Then add your buttons to their respective  invisible container.

```
var n = // Your number of buttons horizontal
var container = Ti.UI.createView({width : "100%", layout: "horizontal" });
for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
   var column = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : (100/n)+"%",
   });
   // Create your button here
   // .....
   // .....

   // Now add it to the column
   column.add(yourNthButton);
   // Now add the column to the container
   container.add(column);
}
```

Comment: The amount of buttons will change, some views have 1, others have 2 or 3.

Comment: So.. Change the percentage? If you have one button, 100%, if you have two, 50%.

Comment: I'd rather not have to keep changing the percentages. The goal is to have them center automatically.

Comment: If you only have three use cases it is not that difficult to change a percentage as you build your views. Can you show some code you have tried? Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have three use cases. There's many sections of my app where I want several buttons to line up horizontally and take up the same width.

Comment: I really do appreciate the effort. There's just one more problem, the number of buttons will change. Sometimes I might have 5, but then depending on some actions it will switch to 6 or 4 etc...

Comment: Just remake the button view again with the new `n`. Wrap the above in a function

Comment: That's specifically what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, then extend my function to remove / add views in the container, then readjust each views percentage.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping your buttons in a view with layout set to 'horizontal'?

```js
var wrapperView = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout     : 'horizontal',
    ...
});

// In a view with horizontal layout,
// the positioning is relative to the preceding element
var buttonOne = Ti.UI.createButton({
   right       : 10, 
   ...
});
wrapperView.add(buttonOne);
```

Untested, but give it a try!

**UPDATE**
Ok, the above code alone won't do what you wanted. I wrote a more complete example here.
Seems a bit clumsy, so if someone has a better solution, please let us know!

```js
// Create our window
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

// Our wrapper view
var wrapperView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width           : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height          : 40,
    top             : 0,
    layout          : 'horizontal',
});

// Add some test buttons to our wrapper
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    wrapperView.add(Ti.UI.createButton({
        title       : 'Test ' + i,
        height      : 30,
    }));
}

// Add wrapperView to our window and open it
win.add(wrapperView);
win.open();

// Wait until "size" becomes available
win.addEventListener('postlayout', distributeButtons);

// Distribute buttons evenly
function distributeButtons() {
     if(wrapperView.children) {
        // Get the width of the wrapper view
        var wrapperWidth = wrapperView.size.width;
        var buttonWidths = 0;
        var buttonSpacer;
        var childrenLength = wrapperView.children.length;

        // Get the button sizes
        for(var i=0; i<childrenLength; i++) {
            buttonWidths += wrapperView.children[i].size.width;
        };

        // Calculate the spaces between the buttons
        buttonSpacer = (wrapperWidth - buttonWidths) / (childrenLength + 2);

        // Set the buttons left value
        for(var i=0; i<childrenLength; i++) {
            wrapperView.children[i].left = buttonSpacer;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can put a toolbar, you can use the "flexspace" button, which will create a space necessary to fill the gap between other buttons. Here's the syntax from simple toolbar example in [titanium docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.Toolbar):

```
var send = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Send',
    style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.DONE,
});

var camera = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.CAMERA,
});

var cancel = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.CANCEL
});

flexSpace = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
});

var toolbar = Titanium.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
    items:[send, flexSpace, camera, flexSpace, cancel],
    bottom:0,
    borderTop:true,
    borderBottom:false
}); 
win.add(toolbar)
```

Comment: Seems like iPhone only.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var yourView = Ti.UI.createView({ layout:"horizontal"});


    var buttonsHolder = Ti.UI.createView({ width:"100%" }); 

    // this view will hold the buttons
    var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton({title:"button1 , left:0"}); // the left button
    var button2 = Ti.UI.createButton({title:"button2"}); // the middle button
    var button3 = Ti.UI.createButton({title:"button3",right:0}); // the right button

    buttonsHolder(button1);
    buttonsHolder(button2);
    buttonsHolder(button3);

    yourView.add(buttonsHolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hieyy bro**

If you are want achieve this using titanium alloy in xml. in that case you can use %.

```
Container ------------width 100%-----layout horizontal---------
   first child--------left 10%------- width 20%
    second child--------left 10%------- width 20%
   third child--------left 10%------- width 20%-----right 10%
```

if you don't get your answer please let me know

Spartacus Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If using Alloy, then I recommend using percentages to control width and position.  Here's an example that centers three small images below a larger image, also centered:

```
<TableViewRow selectionStyle="Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE" backgroundColor="white" layout="vertical">
    <ImageView id="detailsFeaturedImage" top="10"/>
    <View  height="60">
        <View layout="horizontal">
            <View left="25%" width="10%"><ImageView image="images/thumb-up-7@2x.png" onClick="thumb_up" /></View>
            <View left="10%" width="10%"><ImageView image="images/thumb-down-7@2x.png" onClick="thumb_down"/></View>
            <View left="10%" width="10%"><ImageView image="images/flag-7@2x.png" onClick="flag_for_review"/></View>
        </View>
    </View>
</TableViewRow>
```